# Removing just one layer in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm using matplotlibs basemap to plot some wind barbs on top of a pcolor over multiple days using a loop. I can easily change the pcolor by using `set_data()` but now I'm not sure how to replace the barbs.

Is there a way to just remove the barbs without clearing the entire figure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the barbs object save the reference it returns and use it's `remove` function when you are done with it.  The `draw` forces the canvas to re-draw with out the barbs.  Assume that `m` is the `basemap` object.

```
 barbs1,barbs2 = m.barbs(...)
 # some code
 barbs1.remove()
 barbs2.remove()
 plt.draw()
```

Comment: Perfect, this worked great. I knew that it was something simple but I kept trying to use `clear()`.